# Generate Barcode Using JsBarcode library in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, static-resources, js, barcode

Did anyone have used JsBarcode library in LWC in order to generate code 39 barcode, if yes can you please share a sample how I can use the library and generate the barcode. Till now the steps I have done

1. Uploaded the Jsfile from JsBarcode as a static resource
2. Imported the same in Lwc
3. When I am trying to call the function as mentioned in the link : https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/
   I am getting an error.

Hence if somebody can guide me how to use the library it will be of great help below is the link of JsBarcode Library
https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/

Comment: I wrote [a demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Y9H8M4NJLcHP84D0Ocao/src/app.js) that uses the import method instead of a static resource. You can use this method as a better way to bundle your code. There are two extra lines of code you need to include in the copied code to make it importable (included in the demo).

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks a lot for bundle code , my requirement is t save the qr code in the field so I have created a rich text field on the object but not able to understand how to convert the response which I am getting from JsCode into an Image or other format so that I can save it in the rich text field can you please guide me

Comment: Updated the demo to include a way to download the file. To do something else (e.g. save to a RTA field), you just need to pass the data URL (as in the demo) into the file as `<img src=dataURL />` and save to the database. Salesforce will take care of the rest. See [this KA](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320965&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks one again is there a way the code39 can be concise , ie how i can control the width of the barcode

Comment: You can use the width attribute. Note that the specifications state a minimum size, so you should not go smaller than width: 1. Updated demo, again.

Comment: @sfdcfox is a mandate to create an canvas tag in the HTML , can i not create a canvas tag in js below is what I am trying to do

`handleSubmit(event){
    fields.QRCode__c = this.generateCode39(this.poNumber);
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
   }`

`CODE 39
 generateCode39(poNumber){
       console.log('This is code39');
       const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       JsBarcode(
        canvas,
        poNumber, {
          format: "CODE39"
        }
      );
      return canvas.toDataURL();
`

Comment: Sure, you can. I updated the demo again; the canvas is generated directly and used immediately. Just move that logic to generateCode39 and you're good to go.

Comment: @sfdcfox but how I can save that code 39 into the QrCode__c field i dont want to download the code but to save that code into the QrCode__c I am using Ligthning record form and on HandleSubmit I am generating the qrcode

Comment: `const barCodeImage = this.generateCode39(this.poNumber); fields.QR_Code__c = '<img src="'+barCodeImage+'" />`

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `canvas` method of the JsBarcode library as described in the [doc](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/wiki/Browser-Setup). I have tried with a simple code as below and was able to generate the Barcode.

barcodeGenerator.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Generate Barcode">
        <lightning-layout>
            <div class="slds-p-around_small" >
                <template if:false={boolShowSpinner}>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Generate Barcode" onclick={generateBarcode}></lightning-button>
                </template>
                <template if:true={boolShowSpinner}>
                    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large"></lightning-spinner>
                </template>
            </div>
            <canvas data-id="barcode" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

barcodeGenerator.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import barcode from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/barcode";

export default class BarcodeGenerator extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, barcode)
        ]).then(() =>{
            this.renderButtons();
        }).catch(error => {
            window.console.log("Error " + error.body.message);
        });
    }
    renderButtons(){
        this.boolShowSpinner = false;
    }
    generateBarcode(){
        const canvas = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="barcode"]');  
        JsBarcode(canvas, "CODE39 Barcode", {
            format: "CODE39"
          });        
        JsBarcode(".barcode").init(); 
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: how i can save the response from JsBarcode into a richtext field

Comment: @AbhishekKhosla - You need to convert the Canvas content to dataURI and pass it to Apex. Then in Apex save the content as ContentDistribution to save in a RichTextField.