# Generate Barcode Using JsBarcode library in a VF Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, aura

I was able to generate the bar code by following instructions from this link [Generate Barcode Using JsBarcode library in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342552/generate-barcode-using-jsbarcode-library-in-lightning) but I'm unable to generate the same barcode in a visualforce page which loads as a PDF. I keep getting "An error was encountered while processing the file. Some features might not work". Was anyone able to generate barcode in a VF page?

Below is my code:

generateBarCode.html

```
 <template>
<lightning-card title="Generate Barcode">
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Generate Barcode" onclick={handleButtonClick}></lightning-button>
<lightning-layout>
            <canvas data-id="barcode" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

generateBarCode.js

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'; 
import barcode from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/barcode"; 

export default class GenerateBarCode extends LightningElement {
    @api vfData;
  
    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, barcode)   
        ]).then(() =>{
            this.renderButtons();
        }).catch(error => {
            window.console.log("Error " + error.body.message);
        });
    }
    renderButtons(){
      
        this.generateBarcode();
    }
    handleButtonClick() {
        const vfPageUrl = '/apex/generateBarCodeVFPage'; 

        window.open(vfPageUrl, '_blank');
    }

    generateBarcode(){


const canvas = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="barcode"]');
       
        JsBarcode(canvas, this.vfData, {
      
            format: "CODE128",
            displayValue: false 
          });        
       
    }  
}
```

Aura Lightning App: generateBarCodeApp

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
 <aura:dependency resource="generateBarCode" />
```

</aura:application>

VF Page: generateBarCodeVFPage

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" contentType="application/pdf">
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="barcodeContainer"></div>

    <script>
       console.log("Creating LWC component...");
       $Lightning.use("c:generateBarCodeApp", function() {
$Lightning.createComponent(
    "c:generateBarcode",
    {
        vfData: "CODE128 Barcode" // Pass data to the LWC
    },
    "barcodeContainer",
    function() {
        console.log("LWC component created successfully.");
    }
);
});
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript in the Visualforce PDF renderer. See linked questions for references.

Comment: @DavidReed - Thanks for letting me know. Is there any other way we can achieve this requirement?